# EM algorithm when there are too many components to calculate the function Q

Tags: expectation-maximization, latent-variable, finite-mixture-model

Assuming a regression model as follow:

$$\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x}\beta + \mathbf{\varepsilon}$$

where

- $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,...,y_n)^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$,
- $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$
- $\mathbf{\varepsilon}\sim\pi\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma_1}) + (1-\pi)\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma_1}+\sigma^2\mathbf{\Sigma_2})$ is a two components mixture of gaussian distribution
- $\mathbf{\Sigma_1}$, $\mathbf{\Sigma_2}$ are known covariance matrix

We only have observed iid data $(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{y}_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$.

Let $\xi_i\in\{0,1\}$ be the latent data which indicates the distribution of $\varepsilon_i$, i.e.
$$\varepsilon_i|\xi_i\sim\xi_i\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma_1})+(1-\xi_i)\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma_1}+\sigma^2\mathbf{\Sigma_2})$$

Let $\mathbf{\theta}=(\beta,\sigma^2,\pi)$. When it comes to calculate

$$Q(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{\theta^{old}})=\mathbb{E}[l(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{y,\xi})|\mathbf{y,\theta^{old}}]=\sum_{\mathbf{\xi}}l(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{y,\xi})\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{\xi}|\mathbf{y,\theta^{old}}),$$

there are $2^n$ possible combinations of $\mathbf{\xi}=(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)$. It is impossible to calculate $Q(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{\theta^{old}})$ when $n$ is large. Is there anyway to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The log likelihood separates into a sum of $n$ terms corresponding to the $n$ observations and each expectation only involves $\mathbb E[\xi_i|y_i,\theta^\text{old}]$.

Comment: However, the n observations could be correlated as $\mathbf{\Sigma_1}$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma_2}$ are not diagonal matrices.

Comment: Yes. When there is a single $\xi$, this model becomes mixture multivariate gaussian model and EM algorithm can be applied to solve the question, but this may require more observations of $\mathbf{y}$, i.e. $\mathbf{y_1},...,\mathbf{y_n}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$. This question is more like EM algorithm when the observations are not independent.

Comment: Sorry for messing up the index. "but this may require more observations of $\mathbf{y}$, i.e. $\mathbf{y_1},...,\mathbf{y_n}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$." should have meant "but this may require more observations of $\mathbf{y}$, i.e. $\mathbf{y_1},...,\mathbf{y_m}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$."

Answer (score 0):

If one gets an iid $m$-sample $\mathbf y = (\mathbf{y_1},...,\mathbf{y_m})$ from the $n$-dimensional mixture$$\mathbf y \sim \mathbf{\varepsilon}\sim\pi\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{X}\beta,\mathbf{\Sigma_1}) + (1-\pi)\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{X}\beta,\mathbf{\Sigma_1}+\sigma^2\mathbf{\Sigma_2})$$
the completed log-likelihood $l(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{y,\xi})$ satisfies
$$l(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{y,\xi})=\sum_{i=1}^m l(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{y}_i,\xi_i)$$
and hence
$$\mathbb{E}[l(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{y,\xi})|\mathbf{y,\theta^{old}}]=\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}[l(\mathbf{\theta};\mathbf{y}_i,\xi_i)|\mathbf{y}_i,\theta^{old}]$$
is a sum of $m$ terms, each involving only two possible values of $\xi_i$. The nominal $2^m$ size of the latent variable set thus reduces to $2m$ terms.